# Serialize all fields

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I checked out the jquery serialize docs and I am trying to find the best way too serialize all fields in my form and then print the output, the demo has something like:

```
     function showValues() {
          var str = $("form").serialize();
          $("#results").text(str);
        }

        $(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
        $("select").change(showValues);
        showValues();
    });
```

Even then call the serialize on form submit, use return false and have it show them.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, what's the question? Are you looking for commentary? Serialize works well.

Comment: Is this the easiest way to display ALL fields. I am trying to serialize ALL for my form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you putting inside the document.ready method? It looks like you are ending that way... It should be like:

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);
    $("select").change(showValues);
    $('form').bind('submit',function() { showValues(); return false; });
    showValues();
});

function showValues() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $("#results").text(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [forms](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/form) plugin, you can do this:

```
var formData = jQuery('form').formSerialize();
alert(formData);
```

That will serialize all the elements in the form.